# Scriptable disk usage breakdown for a client

Tags: linux, bash, shell, centos7

I am not looking for a tool. I am looking to script out a nice clean breakdown, so I can send it to my VPS users that don't know how to do this.

I was looking for a way to collect a lot of data through a shell script about disk usage. In my job, a LOT of people call in asking "why is my disk full" 
I run du -h --max-depth=1 | sort -rn but that is a little clumsy and I have to keep digging around further....

I am trying to breakdown disk usage via a shell script like this:

```
**home/ is consuming 400GB of disk space**</br>
home/user1 120GB
home/user2 200GB
**var/ is using 100GB of disk space**
```

So far I came up with the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in $(ls -d */ |  grep -v proc);
 do
printf "**** $i has the following breakdown ********\n"

du -h --max-depth=1 $i
done
```

What would be a way to give a cleaner, easier to understand breakdown of disk usage for my users? Just want to be able to wrap a usage in a pretty pink bow and say "good luck"

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/125429/tracking-down-where-disk-space-has-gone-on-linux

Comment: What is wrong with your solution? Why do you call your script "clunky"?

Comment: I wouldn't say your solution is clunky.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you believe that the code works correctly, consider presenting your work (with its unit tests) in a more-complete fashion over at [codereview.se].  You'll likely get some suggestions on making it more efficient, easier to read, and better tested.  Before you do that, make sure to read [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778) first, as some things are done differently over there - e.g. question titles should simply say what the code *does*, as the question is always, "How can I improve this?".

Comment: @InaTsetsova, I *would* say the original has several antipatterns, however. See for example [BashPitfalls #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29): `$(ls)` is innately fault-prone (also discussed in [ParsingLs](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)). Similarly, parameter expansions should never be used in a `printf` format string (placeholders like `%s` should be used, and values passed out-of-band), and expansions should always be quoted. These are all things http://shellcheck.net/ would identify.

Comment: If the intend question was of the form "how can I accomplish *X* on UNIX, including via an answer that involves writing some code *but not limited to same*?" -- which is how I, and the people adding answers that suggest prebuilt tools, read it -- [unix.se] might be the best forum.

Comment: Hey thank you guys for all the word of encouragements! I'm over here doubting my self...  :) I am looking for what I guess @TobySpeight suggested a better way (pretier) way of doing it

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks for that! I am going to look into that... Tried to loop find instead of LS .... would that be something a little less fault prone?

Comment: @CharlesWilson, ...so, `find` definitely has approaches that are safer than `ls`, but `for x in $(find ...)` still has same issues. See `find ... -exec ...`, or `find ... -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' piece; do ...; done`, as described in the "Actions", "Complex Actions", and "Actions in Bulk" sections in [UsingFind](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy was reviewing the TOS for this board, Thought I was in scope, I am writing a script to pretify a disk break down for VPS cusotmers that don't know how to monitor their own stuff :/ haha. Not looking for tools, or anything like that

Comment: So, general guideline: If you hit a *specific question about bash* in the course of building the script (for example, "why doesn't my script work with a volume that has a space in its directory name?"), it would definitely be in scope. If you were looking for a bash language feature, again, definitely in-scope. If you were asking why a bash language feature didn't work, definitely in-scope. "What's the best way to accomplish *this larger goal* in bash?" is fuzzier; sometimes it might be in-scope, sometimes it won't. The more specific the question, the better.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy  makes sense!!!!!!  thank you sir! I will adress this in the future. and again thank you for the insights.

Comment: @CharlesWilson: It's often about the way the question is phrased - check out this meta question on what is an off-topic recommendation question- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question. I've edited your question a bit to make it clearer what your issue is and why your solution might not be enough for you. However, only you can fill in the blanks. Make sure you make it clear what the issue is and what you're looking for, and why your current script doesn't address it. Focuses on the problem and not the solution. Then it wouldn't be off-topic.

Answer (score 2):

Give a try to [ncdu (NCurses Disk Usage)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncdu), for example:

```
$ ncdu -q -x
```

The options:

```
-q  Quiet mode. While scanning or importing the directory, ncdu will
    update the screen 10 times a second by default, this will be
    decreased to once every 2 seconds in quiet mode. Use this
    feature to save bandwidth over remote connections.
```

And

```
 -x  Do not cross filesystem boundaries, i.e. only count files and
     directories on the same filesystem as the directory being
     scanned.
```

More examples here: https://dev.yorhel.nl/ncdu/man#EXAMPLES

Comment: It's a good tool suggestion, but if this is an appropriate answer, the question was clearly off-topic here.

Comment: Thank you! and that tool would be good, If the customer knew what they were doing, I am looking to make  a quick little, "hey your disk usage is at 400G usage because  home/ uses 200G" and break it down dummy style. lol

Answer (score 2):

Here's an alternative solution. You can use tree to list the contents of the directory in a 'tree-like' format. You can then combine it with a disk usage flag to see the nested directories and their size.

```
tree -L 2 --du -h
```

The '-L' flag defines the depth or level of your query.

This will give you output like this:

[image: Screenshot of tree command output in the command line]

You can even create an xml file you can open in the browser like so:

```
tree -L 2 --du -h -H s > disk_usage.html
```

You can then open the file in a browser and the output will look like this:

[image: Screenshot of the xml output when opened in the browser]

Hope this helps!

Comment: !!! I forgot tree!!!!!!!! is that scriptable? so I can say, just throw it in my script  in lu of DU ?

Comment: @CharlesWilson if you write it in a file, and make it executable, it will run. Try it in your script, it should work. If the answer works for you, don't forget to accept it :)

Answer (score 0):

you snippet is a good start, you can't make this thing in 1 line.
some folders, you need a depth > 1 (home) and some other a depth = 1 (var)